# jquery resizing of a div when clicking a link

Tags: jquery

Can someone explain how I can resize a div using jquery when someone clicks on a link.

This code isn't working:

```
$(".a_link").click(function() {
    $("#insur_main").css("width","800px");
 });
```

Comment: Without seeing the HTML I would venture a guess that you just need to add a return false; to the end of your click function.

Comment: _"Isn't working"_ isn't very informative, nor is posting JS without the minimal HTML that it is operating on. Your code as presented would work for a particular set of HTML and CSS markup.

Comment: sorry, I should have explained more, looking at the html I found the error.  I was already including some other "onclick" events hardcoded, when I removed those, the jquery worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to enclose your statement in $(document).ready() to ensure that your event is binded when the element is completely loaded.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $(".a_link").click(function() {
        $("#insur_main").css("width","800px");
    });
 });
```

Comment: And I found if I remove the hard coded onclick event on the element and just let juery do the event handling it worked.

Comment: If the page hangs or takes some time to load the link event will not be bind until the page stop loading the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work

```js
$(".a_link").click(function() {
    $("#insur_main").css("width","800px");
 });
```

```css
#insur_main
{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:red; 
}
```

```html
<div id="insur_main"> </div>

<a href="#" class="a_link">Resize DIV</a>
```

Comment: please add some explaination to your code. An good answer is not just a code

Answer (score 0):

It might be a problem with the order of your script.

**[See this example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vTDZJ/)**

```
<script>
    alert( "Doesn't exist yet " + $(".a_link").length );
</script>

<a href="#" class="a_link">Link 01</a>
<script>
    alert( "Now it does exist " + $(".a_link").length );
</script>

<script>
$(function() {
    // ondomready it exists
    alert( "Ready " + $(".a_link").length );
});
</script>
```

You might be calling the script before the element is rendered. It might not exist on the DOM yet. You have to execute the script after it enters the DOM.

Comment: thanks for your help.  I should have included more html...the problem ended up being I already had other onclick events tied to the element that were hard coded...when removed it worked.